# How to transform a Mono to a Mono<Void> in case of error

Tags: project-reactor

I'm trying to write a method that does something like this

```
   Mono<A> ma = networkCall(); //this might fail
   Mono<Void> mv  = ma.map( a -> ....)  #some logic to perform with `A`

   return mv;
```

The trick is, `ma` might very well fail and then I would want to just log the situation and return a `Mono<Void>` that completes with no error.

Looking at the `Mono` api I just found `onErrorResume` or `onErrorReturn` but both would take a function that returns an `A` (which I can't fabricate), while I would like to return a `Void`. 
I would imagine the solution is quite simple, but couldn't quite find the right operations for this. 
So, what operations should I apply to `ma` to transform it into a `Mono<Void>` in case of error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just found onErrorResume or onErrorReturn but both would take a function that returns an A

`onErrorReturn()` indeed requires you to return an `A`, but `onErrorResume()` just requires you to return a `Mono<A>`, which can be empty.

So you can use:

- `doOnNext()` to perform your logic with `A` if the call is successful;
- `doOnError()` to log your error if the call is not successful;
- `onErrorResume()` to return an *empty* result
- `then()` to convert the result into a `Mono<Void>`.

Something like:

```
networkCall()
        .doOnNext(a -> doSomethingWith(a))
        .doOnError(e -> e.printStackTrace())
        .onErrorResume(e -> Mono.empty())
        .then();
```